# Change "global" datasource dynamically

Tags: coldfusion, datasource, coldfusion-10, application.cfc

I usually set application-wide datasource name in the Application.cfc first rows:

```
<cfscript>THIS.datasource="mydsn";</cfscript>
```

What if I need to change it in certain part of my code?

To be specific, I mean:

- if the cgi.server_name equals "www.firsturl.com"  => this.datasource = "firstdsn"
- if the cgi.server_name equals "www.secondurl.com" => this.datasource = "seconddsn"

Can I do that for each request?

Comment: This would be pretty easy for you to simply test and see what happens, surely?  Just put a conditional around your declaration of `this.datasource` in your Application.cfc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, my comment on your original post notwithstanding - that the best way to find out these things is just *try it* and see what happens, the answer is: yes.

Application.cfc is poorly named, because it implies it's kind of application-specific, but in reality the entire thing is instantiated every request.  That some of the event handlers only run in given situations (onApplicationStart / onSessionStart etc) is neither here nor there: the whole thing runs every request.  So as with any CFC being instantiated, the pseudo-constructor code (where you make your this-scoped variable declarations) is also run every request.

This means that yes you can conditionally set any of those variables based on REQUEST-specific information (request, CGI, URL, FORM etc; but not APPLICATION or SESSION).  So your condition based on a CGI variable will work just fine.

But don't take my word for it: try it!  Always try these things.

Finally, just to plug myself slightly, I discuss when things run in Application.cfc in some depth on my blog, in [this article](http://adamcameroncoldfusion.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/more-on-applicationcfc-when-things-run.html).  Maybe give it a read, and perhaps look at the other articles on Application.cfc whilst you're there.

Comment: I haven't tested this, but I would presume that care is required using this method if any queries are happening inside of onSessionEnd, since the CGI scope wont have the expected values.

Comment: Yeah, there's some weirdness (and not what one would necessarily expect).  Too much (and not on topic) to go through, but I cover it on my blog: http://adamcameroncoldfusion.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/curious-behaviour-with-this-scoped.html